# Best Pratice Setting global, changeable parameters in Python package

Tags: python, package, settings

I have made a python package with a basic structure like this (this is only the code structure).

```
mypackage
    mypackage
        __init__.py
        module1.py
        module2.py
```

In the **init** file I import functionalities from module1 and module2. The problem: I would like to make a package-parameter handler, such that you can change general behavior of the package by simply changing this parameter. Example:

```
import mypackage
mypackage.settings['show_progressbar'] = False
```

In this example settings is a dictionary. For inspiration I have considered matplotlib's rcparams. However, I do not know how to implement this. Placing the settings dict in the init file while also using it in module1 and module2 will yield circular import.

init.py

```
from mypackage.module1 import function1
from mypackage.module2 import function2
settings = {'show_progressbar': True}
```

module1.py

```
from mypackage import settings

def function1(show_progressbar=settings['show_progressbar']):
     ...some code with a progressbar ...
```

So how do I make an editable settings dictionary (or other object) that may be used to control behavior of an instance of the module?

Comment: maybe you should put it in separated file and then you can import it to `__init__` and `model1` without `circular import`. But I don't know if they will use the same `settings` or two different `settings`

Comment: That was my thought as well. But as you write, I do not know whether it will end up changing the settings. I am looking for best practice, hence my question.

Comment: first you could try to use it and if it will not work then search other method.